# Return true or false from a block method inside a method

Tags: ruby

An `Item` `has_many` `Pieces`. I have two methods, one that finds out if the Piece is available and one that finds out if an Item has available pieces.

```
  # in piece.rb
  def available?(current_user, piece)
    if piece.status == 1
      true
    elsif piece.status == 2
      false
    elsif piece.status == 3
      true if piece.friend_id == current_user.id
    end
  end

  #in item.rb
  def available?(current_user, user, item)
    false
      item.pieces.each do |piece|
        if piece.available?(current_user, piece)
          true
        end
      end
  end
```

My `available?` method in `Item` is wrong. I want it to return `true` if an `Item` has available `pieces`, and `false` if not. Theory behind my code is that the method returns `false` unless there is a piece that returns `true`. When I do it in the console all I get are the pieces in a hash, not true or false.

Can anyone solve my problem or tell me a better way to do this?

Comment: this seems just wrong: `Piece#available?(current_user, piece)`. why is piece again an argument? it's another piece? same for `Item`.

Comment: No its the item, in other words, is the item available based on its pieces. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to check whether item has at least one available piece, the method can look like this:

```
def available?(current_user, user, item)
  item.pieces.each do |piece|
    return true if piece.available?(current_user, piece)
  end
  false
end
```

Comment: Definitely a better way. Thanks!!

Comment: To elaborate on tokland's point, just do `item.pieces.any? {|p| piece.available?(current_user, p) }`. The function definition isn't strictly necessary.

Answer (score 10):

Use `Enumerable#any?`:

```
def available?(current_user, user, item)
  item.pieces.any? do |piece|
    piece.available?(current_user, piece)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Inferring from your code I think that `available?` method in `Piece.rb` doesn't need a second argument of piece because it's an instance method of Piece. So I suggest you refactor the method to:

```
def available_to?(current_user)
  if status == 1
    true
  elsif status == 2
    false
  elsif status == 3
    true if friend_id == current_user.id
  end
end
```

It will give you a more clean interface.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `piece` is present twice (which makes little sense). Note however that the expression you wrote can be improved: 1) `true if friend_id == current_user.id` -> `friend_id == current_user.id`. 2) It can be re-written as a very simple boolean expression: `status == 1 || (status == 3 && friend_id == current_user.id)`.

Comment: yeah, that's right and that's why ruby is so great =) one can refactor a bunch of if-statements in a one line of code

Comment: I know it needs a refactor, I'm just struggling to get my head around the whole thing still. An item is available if it has at least one available piece. Can I use the method in Piece for item too?

Comment: Yeah, `available` method of `Item` also doesn't need arguments `user`, because it's never used, and `item`, because again it's the instance method and you can access Item object through `self`. So you can use the method which tokland wrote in his answer, but just delete user and item arguments. It should look like this: `def available?(current_user) pieces.any? do |piece| piece.available?(current_user) end end`

Comment: tokenvolt and tokland - Thanks